# Show single legend for grouped 3D lines in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, legend

The default behavior of plotly is to automagically add several legends when the data is grouped by a variable. In my case, I would like set only one legend despite the group. Is this possible at all? The example below illustrates my question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

lines_data <- tibble(
  x = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)),
  y = c(rep(5, 10), rep(7, 10)),
  z = rep(seq(from = 0.5, to = 5.7, length.out = 10), times = 2),
  gp = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10)
)

plotly::plot_ly(
  data = lines_data,
  x = ~x, 
  y = ~y,
  z = ~z,
  split = ~gp,
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "lines",
  line = list(color = "red", width = 10)
)
```

[image: plolty 3D lines]

I would like to have a single legend that says "line".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701320/add-specific-legend-to-r-plotly-chart

Comment: I like that you have got an easily reproducible example here but I wonder if it reflects the actual data. I don't understand why you would have the label "line" for a line, rather than the group which the line belongs to.

Comment: @SamR You are right. It does not truly reflect the actual data. My data is a bit more complex. My true goal is to plot a surface as well as several 3D lines. The 3D lines are drawn according to a group variable and I don't want to have one legend for each 3D line. All lines represent an indicator (i.e. profit) and I just want one legend to say "Profit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this in R, *normally.* At this point, I believe it just doesn't work for the type `scatter3d`. I have a workaround, though.

This uses the library `htmlwidgets`. I didn't call the library; I just attached it to the function call. The `onRender` call looks for the last trace in the legend and removes it. If you wanted to remove the first element, you would just change `last` to `first`. (JQuery is sneaky like that...with the 'literalness')

```
plotly::plot_ly(
  data = lines_data,
  x = ~x, 
  y = ~y,
  z = ~z,
  split = ~gp,
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "lines",
  name = "line",
  legendgroup = "line",       # added so you can still toggle traces
  line = list(color = "red", width = 10)) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(){
    $('svg g.traces').last().remove() 
  }")
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know that we could directly interact with plotly like that. Is is also possible to use vanilla Javascript? I started learning Javascript when JQuery was no longer the coolest kid on the block.

Comment: You can use JS with any widget-based R objects. RMarkdown is JS-friendly, as well (and any other programming language).  There is probably more, but that's all I can think of off the top of my head. When you go through `htmlwidgets`, don't expect a 1=1 with JS (or JQuery). It could override what you write. For most things that need to be looped, HTML will loop it for you if you code it as if it's a single element. There are some other ODD things that happen... but still REALLY useful. (I call it JS-ish.)